# How do I reset my keyboard layout?

Tags: xorg, keyboard, keyboard-layout

How can I reset my keyboard layout after modifying it with `xkbcomp`?

Is there a way to do this without restarting X?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try:

```
setxkbmap us
```

(Replacing `us` with the keyboard layout you want). If using a variant (e.g. `intl`), try

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant intl
```

[Here's a list of keyboard layouts](https://web.archive.org/web/20161203032703/http://pastebin.com/v2vCPHjs).

Comment: Where can I get a list of the names of the keyboard layouts? For example, how do I find out what to use for USA International?

Comment: I created this list from the contents of /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst: http://pastebin.com/v2vCPHjs
For USA International, do `setxkbmap us -variant intl`. (Only one dash!)

Comment: Could you please add the pastebin link or a `file:///usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` link to your answer to improve readability?

Comment: this answer gives temporarily solution, after reboot system, possible switches would be default session

Comment: This also works if you run synergy and you have a modifier key, e.g. the shift key, apparently stuck down.

Comment: is there any permanent solution to persist this changes, because it seems like after reboot it goes back to original state..

Comment: This is not a real reset command

Comment: Isn't the same list of keyboard layouts as in `man xkeyboard-config`?

Answer (score 12):

Check current layout and options:

```
setxkbmap -print -verbose 10
```

Reset layout to US and reset options:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option
```

(Without the empty `-option` parameter, no options would be reset.)

Use the first command to check the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setxkbmap -layout us`. It looks to completely reset the changes