# PageUp, PageDown, Home and End on laptop don't work in X11

Tags: keyboard, xorg

I have Dell Inspirion 3168 with Xubuntu 16.10. I noted a problem.

PageUp, PageDown, Home and End on laptop's keyboard (fn+arrow keys) work in console, in evtest, showkey (emit right keycode, as example PgDn is 109), but don't work in X11 (xev and X applications). But on external USB keyboard these keys work properly.

Comment: reset your keyboard `http://askubuntu.com/questions/395/how-do-i-reset-my-keyboard-layout` If works let us know

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I have this problem in a clean system to.

Comment: But I have got some new information.

Comment: Firstly if I press e.g. page down, it sticks (in X11 applications it is as I continue to press it). Then, as I understood, system begins to ignore events. But it doesn't seem that key has stuck on hardware level, evtest's and showkey's behavior is correct.
Same problem was described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dell_Inspiron_11_3000_(3162)#Keyboard

Comment: And after key was locked,  here is xinput query-state 14 | grep down
...
 key[112]=down

xinput thinks that key is pressed, but it's released.

Comment: And here is the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/892709/dell-inspiron-11-3162-home-end-pgup-pgdn-keys-not-working

Comment: The problem is with keyboard mapping you can find a solution in http://www.artwork.com/support/unix/keyboard_mapping.htm If resolved let me know