# How can i reset my keyboard layout in xwayland in ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, xorg, wayland, reset

Unfortunately I changed my keyboard layout and now my keyboard acts like unreal.
I installed a software called xkeycaps and then came this problem

I tried setxkbmap and it works with a warning. After restarting my device it's staying in the previous layout.
Please someone help me to solve this problem
ubuntu version 23.04

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubuntu. Please edit your question to include information on how you changed the layout in the first place. Also Ubuntu version and posibly DE would help us help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset my keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/395/how-do-i-reset-my-keyboard-layout)